# Unable to effect generator in exchangelib for loop

Tags: python, generator, exchangelib

I am unable to succeed in getting a server-side generator to yield to a client-side javascript while for looping through exchangelib items. I'm going in circles. The progress bar does not progress beyond the initial 9% - set by the bar_min variable below. I can only assume its something peculiar to the exchangelib for loop... Would appreciate some expert input to my amateur efforts, with thanks. Here is the server side snippet from a flask script:

```
@flask_app.route('/demo/process_ews', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def pulsemail_EWS():

    __OUTLOOK_EMAIL__ = session.get('__OUTLOOK_EMAIL__')
    __OUTLOOK_PASSWORD__ = session.get('__OUTLOOK_PASSWORD__')
    __DBUSER__ = session.get('__DBUSER__')

    def generate():

        subject_actual = ""
        
        bar_min = 9
        bar_max = 100
        increments = (bar_max - bar_min) / config.__EMAILCOUNT__
        increments = int(round(increments))
        yield "data:" + str(bar_min) + "\n\n"
            
        full_path = config.__USER_DB_PATH__+__DBUSER__+"_pulsemail"
        full_path = full_path.replace("'","")

        __LAST_ANALYSYS__ = setDate()
        
        account = connect_to_EWS(__OUTLOOK_EMAIL__, __OUTLOOK_PASSWORD__, __OUTLOOK_EMAIL__)

        for item in account.inbox.filter(datetime_received__gt=__LAST_ANALYSYS__+timedelta(0,1)).only('subject','text_body','datetime_received','sender','cc_recipients'):
            
            yield "data:" + str(bar_min) + "\n\n"
            bar_min += increments
            time.sleep(0.5)


    return flask_app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

and here is the client side JS:

```
<script>
  var source = new EventSource("/demo/process_ews");

  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', event.data+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', event.data);
    $('.progress-bar-label').text(event.data+'%');

    if(event.data == 100){
      source.close()

      var begin = document.getElementById('begin');
      begin.textContent = 'Inbox Email Retrieval Complete';

      location.replace("/demo/ews_output_sent")
    }

  }

  function stop() {
    source.close(); // this stops the feed
    location.replace("/demo/ews_output_sent")
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Try reducing the problem first. For example, you can replace `for item in account.inbox.filter(...)` with `while True:` to find out whether your exchangelib code is part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I actually tried something similar with the following snippet which did behave as expected: `while x <= 100: yield "data:" + str(x) + "\n\n" x = x + 10 time.sleep(0.5)` < mini-md means I can't put on distinct lines, apols but hope yo get the idea

Comment: Ok. Then you can rip out all the JavaScript code and focus on why your exchangelib query does not return any items.

Comment: Thanks Erik, i did more debugging and realised the math was too infinitesimal to see the prog bar move! Geez. My apologies; I resorted to an integer based computation for the loop which works fine. Thanks for weighing and nudging me on. Have a nice day!